# Determine if a java execution from another java application was done successfully

Tags: java, testing, logging, execute

I have an application that calls a java test class in a specified location of my PC. The path is hard-coded for now, and I checked that it worked by executing it from the command line (in case you want to see it: `java -cp C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace\test\build\test.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore us.test.DynamicWebserviceInvocationTest`), so I know that the command works fine.

The thing is, when I do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`, if I try to log the resulting InputStream and ErrorStream of its resulting process, the program stucks. I tried with exitValue() and waitFor(), but the first throws an incompletition error and the second also gets stuck. The weird thing is that if I don't touch anything of this (the streams, or using the functions), the program has no problem ending.

So my question is: **Why could this be?** The next step is to build the command with given parameters, but if I can't see the resulting inputs I can't be completely sure if the tests are running or not.

The code, in case you want to see it:

```
Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
logger.debug("Attempting to execute the test {} at path {}",classpath,applicationLocation);

String command="java -cp C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\workspace\\test\\build\\test.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore us.test.DynamicWebserviceInvocationTest";
Process process=runtime.exec(command);
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Just as a test: can you try reading both streams one row at a time and alternating between them as long as the process is alive?

Comment: Connect each other with a local socket and communicate.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper: I tried it and it printed the whole thing and exited fine. Now I just need to handle the output. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely must read both streams in separate threads. (Read the Javadoc of the [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class). If you wait for the end, or read first one stream before the other it can happen that the output buffer of the command fills up and it will block (on stdout or stderr, depending on what you read first). Normally you use waitFor() in the current thread and have background thread draining the outputs (this also allows detecting end of child process without polling).

If you want to use only one (additional) thread you can redirect stderr to stdout. If you want to avoid to read the streams at all, you can set the 
ProcessBuilder features [inheritIO()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29). This allows the stream to be written to the existing output and so you do not need a thread to read independently.

There are BTW various libararies which offer exec tools (for example [Apache Commons Exec has some streams](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/LogOutputStream.html)) which offer active stream draining, logging or pumping for `Process`.

In addition to that it might also be a good idea to first close stdin, in case the command waits for input: `p.getOutputStream().close();`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close the 2 streams:

```
    String command="java -cp C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\workspace\\test\\build\\test.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore us.test.DynamicWebserviceInvocationTest";
    Process process=runtime.exec(command);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command 
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    stdInput.close();

    // read any errors from the attempted command 
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    stdError.close();
```

Comment: It is not safe to do that in a single thread. It depends on the amount of data the child outputs and the amount of buffer the OS uses if it works or not. In your case if the process wants to write 8k error messages and then 1 line normal output the 8k will fill up the error buffer and not write any stdout at all, your first loop will block and never drain stderr.